Reactjs monorepo or what
In my react application, after the person logs in, we redirect to different subdomains according to the user type and these different subdomains contain different content. the part where the administrator enters is called portal and the part where the members enter are different screens. what should I do to separate them? should I use monorepo or should I write the codes in the same project? if I should use monorepo, which tool should I use (nx, turbo..etc.)?
please help me idk what should i do
